# Javascript Html Swedish characters strange behavior

Tags: javascript, html, symbols

I would like to ask a question regarding a strange behavior I face using the escape Ascii characters for some Swedish chars.

More specifically, in order to support a multilingual site, I have a json file where I have specified all required messages in Swedish, i.e. 'Avancerad s&*#246*;k'.

Then when the page loads the first time, I set this value to an input text and it is displayed properly: 'Avancerad sök'. But when I click a button and set again the value of this input text I get: 'Avancerad s&*#246*;k'.

Does anyone have faced a similar problem?

Thanks a lot!

Code:

```
q('#keyword').val(qLanguage.qAdvancedHint);
```

I execute this code both times. `qLanguage` is an object which I fill it from the json file and qAdvancedHint a specific key.

Comment: Code? http://jsfiddle.net? Something? Help us help you.

Comment: if ("Avancerad sök" == "Avancerad sök") return "All is good" :) How does it look when it's incorrect?

Comment: Code added. Apologies for not adding it the first time...

Comment: I don't want to seem pedantic, but ASCII doesn't represent Swedish characters or any other (international) ones really. I wonder if the problem here is the default encoding for your web page.

Comment: To back that up, I strongly recommend reading this:  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know have the specific encoding is called. But tested with js's unescape method, but didn't work.

However a solution, a bad/ugly one, could be to ask jQuery to parse it for you then add it as a value property:

```
var text = $("<span/>").html(qLanguage.qAdvancedHint).text();
q('#keyword').val(text);
```

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot!! And apologize once again for the not-so-helping description of the question :(